# Can EXSLT date-and-time functions be used in XSLT 1.0 and processed using browser engine?

Tags: browser, date, xslt, exslt

My goal: I need to transform a "date of birth" element in XML document to "age" value using XSL stylesheet and generate XHTML page. I am using the web browser (e.g. IE/FF) directly to open the XML document.

I know XSLT 2.0 has built-in date and time functions, but I think no browser currently support this. So, I've been trying to use EXSLT functions instead without success.

Here are my sample test files:

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<test>
</test>
```

test.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                 xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="date:date-time()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Error on IE8:

```
Namespace 'http://exslt.org/dates-and-times' does not contain any functions.
```

Error on FF4:

```
Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown XPath extension function was called.
```

Does that mean EXSLT is not supported by major web browsers? Do I have to use XSLT proccessor like SAXON/Xalan? Am I doing something wrong? Is there an alternative way?

Comment: I don't know about any browser with an XSLT processor fully supporting EXSLT. Only `node-set()` is widely supported. Two options: pass the current date as parameter to the transformation; use Saxon-CE beta.

Comment: I googled for Saxon-CE but found only those versions: HE, PE, EE. I will try using XSLT 2.0 with Saxon-HE.

Comment: See http://saxonica.com/ce/doc/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the EXSLT support matrix as a reference:

> The following XSLT processors support date:date-time:

```
SAXON from Michael Kay (version 6.4.2)
Xalan-J from Apache (version 2.4.D1)
4XSLT, from 4Suite. (version 0.12.0a3)
libxslt from Daniel Veillard et al. (version 1.0.19)
```

`libxslt` is used by Chrome, Opera and Safari, but `date-time()` does not work since EXSLT is disabled:

> I don't think it makes sense to add functions piecemeal; after nearly 5 years is there still anything preventing libexslt being included in the build and exsltRegisterAll() being called from registerXSLTExtensions() in XSLTExtensions.cpp?

IE uses `MSXML`, which has the following support:

> MSXML4 provided two great extension functions, ms:format-date() and ms:format-time() to aim at the latter problem, but they are not supported in .NET or MSXML3.

There is no `ms:date-time()` function, but there is an [MSXSL extension](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/date-time/date.msxsl.xsl).

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:ecma ="about:ecma">
    <msxsl:script implements-prefix="ecma">
     <![CDATA[
      function GetCurrentDateTime()
        {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = currentTime.getDate();
        var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
        return(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
        }
     ]]>
    </msxsl:script>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="ecma:GetCurrentDateTime()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Firefox uses [Transformiix](http://xml.coverpages.org/xslSoftware.html#mitre), which has [support](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc/xslt/#ft-exslt-date-time) for EXSLT `date-time()` since FF6.

**References**

- [MDN: EXSLT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/EXSLT)
- [EXSLT - date:date-time](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/date-time/)
- [XSL Transformations (XSLT) in Mozilla](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/xslt/)
- [Test Cases for XSLT support in browsers](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc/xslt/#ft-exslt-date-time)
- [Mozilla Bug 603159 - implement exslt-date:date-time()](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=603159)
- [Webkit Bug 4079 Support EXSLT with libexslt](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4079)
- [Mozilla Bug 265254 - support exlst:date](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=265254)
- [Transformiix: Elements and Functions Available](http://www.xmlplease.com/efa/efa-transformiix.html)
- [Building Practical Solutions with EXSLT.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468553.aspx)
- [Microsoft XPath Extension Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256453)

Comment: "*Use the EXSLT support matrix as a reference*" if you mean the EXSLT site (http://www.exslt.org/func/), that hasn't been updated in ages.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Exactly. So, in reference to the question at hand, that simply means libxslt has supported date-time() for ages. Please read the rest of the answer for more recent references.